# Grant a service account access permission for subscription/num_outstanding_messages of subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way I can grant a service account access permission for subscription/num_outstanding_messages of subscription?
Instead of granting the permission to whole project of the subscription belongs to, I just want to grant permission for access the subscription only.

I can't find the answer from the documents:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `monitoring.timeSeries.list` permission acts on the project level ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control#api_permissions)), so you can't only give permission to get stats on one subscription in a project.

It is possible to have subscriptions in a different project from the topic (so long as the creator has `projects.subscriptions.create` perm in both projects) and even for an app to fetch from a subscription from a different project that the app runs in (so long as the app has `projects.subscriptions.pull`).  This does allow you to achieve what you want, here are some possible set-ups:

- Separate push/pull: publisher & topic in project A; subscription, subscriber and stats-reader in project B.
- Only separate subscription itself: publisher, topic, subscriber and stats-reader in project A; subscription in project B.